Tests run with Playwright Test for VSCode are not retried
The retries is set to 2 in playwright.config.ts as follows.
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: 2,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    }
  ]
});

The test code to be executed is as follows.
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async () => {
    throw new Error('error.');
});


Retry works if I do it in the following way.
npx playwright test

Retry works
But, tests run with Playwright Test for VSCode are not retried.
tests run with Playwright Test for VSCode
Retry not works
Does Playwright Test for VSCode support retrying test runs?
Version
Playwright Test for VSCode: 1.1.7
Playwright: 1.43.1
